New GUID attached when I inserted Secure Boot Keys
I have a desktop with Asrock B550M pro motherboard and its firmware is UEFI.
The setup offers custom key management under Secure Boot.
I downloaded Windows UEFI CA 2023.crt from Microsoft as well as created by own certificate using OpenSSL.
I appended both the certificates as Public Certificates in db variable from the UEFI’s Custom Key Management interface.
After saving changes I went into UEFI again and confirmed that the keys are preserved, and they indeed are.
However I notice that a totally new GUID is attached to both certificates than the original one.
My own key certificate GUID starts with 4DB62.. and that of Microsoft CA-2023 is 77FA9ABD...
However see the screenshot, a new single but different GUID is attached to both certificates.
Is this the way it is or did I do something wrong? Is it simply because the custom key management mode (I guess setup mode) is not a strict mode and I am freely allowed to manipulate the keys?
Secure Boot is working fine. It now even can run EFI files signed by my own key created using OpenSSL.


Does the other two GUID match for the other two certificates? Trying to diagnose if the GUID should be different or match.

The other two certificates (2011) are from Microsoft but default present in the firmware as added by OEM. I only added CA_2023.crt and my own say SelfDBcert.cer directly from the GUI setup in UEFI.

The GUID isn't a property of the certificate – it describes the db entry itself, so that entries from different sources could be distinguished by management tools.
For example, 77FA9ABD... is used for all certificates coming from Microsoft, as their OEM requirements define. Similarly, your firmware might generate a GUID to mark "certificates added manually via setup GUI". If you're updating db directly through EFI variables, you get to specify the GUID as part of the new data.

It doesn't have the Microsoft GUID because the db update adding this entry didn't come from Microsoft – OP says in the post that they installed the 2023 certificate through their UEFI GUI interface. I have no idea what you're referring to by "database was definitely designed to be updated". Yes, that's literally why the GUIDs exist.

They are the same source: both were installed manually by OP through the EFI setup screen. If the 2023 certificate had come through Windows Update (in the form of a pre-signed db update) it would've had the Microsoft GUID instead.

Copy, that’s what I was looking to confirm.

No matter how many times I do it it's taking the same GUID and I checked that it's not same as the GUID (UUID) of the motherboard. It seems it has another GUID embedded in the firmware meant for me (the user) as owner. I also inserted Microsoft's CA 2023 KEK.crt under KEK and it's assigning the same GUID to that one as well. UEFI Setup does nothing when I click on listed certificate in the UI, so it does not seem possible to get further details from within UEFI.
